# Method in Thread stop my UI - Python Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, scheduler

I am trying to run some periodic (scheduler) method asynchronously, so that UI thread is not blocked.

My current code is:

```
class Job():

    def run(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_inside_thread, args=[])
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start() 

    def run_inside_thread(self):

        schedule.every(self.tick).seconds.do(self.call_method)

        while True:
            if self.isRunning:
                schedule.run_pending()
```

I use  `if self.isRunning:`, so that I can stop and start the tasks.
The problem is that this is blocking my UI (but only on server - on my local development machine UI is working)

What I am doing wrong? By my understanding code should run async on another thread (not UI one).

I see the "fix" that you put `time.sleep(1)`, but this mean that I can't run method sunner then 1 second. If for example I do `time.sleep(0.1)` it doesn't work. (UI thread is blocked)

Comment: What do you mean by UI thread?

Comment: By UI thread I mean that if I lunch localhost:8000 then I get my index page. (or on server some other host) Also all my rest API endpoints are blocked. - If I call them come to timeout

Comment: It might be memory issue. Please try with Queue.

Comment: No the memory is low. The CPU usage however is very high. I don't know what you mean by try with Queue ( I know what in general Queue is)

Comment: Queue example: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel

Comment: This solutions will not solve my problem. It still contains while 1: witch will run intensively and block UI thread. He solve this with time.sleep(1), witch I put in my question that doesn't help me.